# Why DirectRunner is not executing steps from pipeline, while DataflowRunner it works

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple pipeline, with one Windowing function. Steps are as following:

- read from pubsub
- debugstep (printing aaa)
- window 10s
- debugstep (print bbb)
- TextIO.writeDynamic to gcs.

And, on Dataflow I've got pretty nice debug messages, so that I know that steps after windowing functions are executed correctly.

However, I need to debug stuff locally, and unfortunately my "debugstep" after window is not executed at all. No messages, no debugger attached. Nothing. Every once in a while it processes a window, but it feels very unstable.

Whats the reason for this? I've seen this problem many years ago when Dataflow was at its early stages, now, 4 years later, it still is an issue. Maybe am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean  locally?  Can you provide more details about testing environment?

Comment: I think you need to give more details for some better answers.  Specifically, usually a minimal working example is expected / helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use print inside Dataflow. Use logger instead:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

You can use `logging.debug()` inside a DoFn:

```py
class JustPrintSomething (beam.DoFn):

   def process (self, stuff):
      logging.debug(f"Stuff received: f{stuff}")
      yield stuff
```

This should send to stdout the message in DirectRunner. You'll get the log messages in Stackdriver if you're using Dataflow.

Comment: Well, indeed. One should use logging if want to see something. However, this question is 1) about java, 2) about not executing step at all.